# Cartthrob vs PHP 7.3: (each) deprecated

Tags: cartthrob

When adding price modifier configurator fieldtype to product channel i get a php error when creating a product:

"(each) is deprecated"
system/user/addons/cartthrob/helpers/data_formatting_helper
re88: while (list($key, $values) = each($input))

I changed this php re to:
while (list($key, $values) = current($input))

Seems to work fine, can anyone validate my solution?